# C++ copy constructor issue with parent/child classes

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I've run into a problem with copy constructors...I assume there is a basic answer to this and I'm missing something obvious - maybe I'm doing something entirely wrong - but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Basically, I have a parent class and child class.  The parent class contains a vector of pointers to a (different) base class object. The child class wants to instead store pointers to objects derived from that base object.

Here's a pseudocode sample, if that helps:

```
// Base classes
class ItemRev {
  ...
}

class Item {

protected:

vector<ItemRev *> m_revPtrVec;

}


Item::Item(const Item &inputItemObj)
{
  // Copy contents of the input object's item rev pointer vector
  vector<ItemRev *>::const_iterator vecIter = (inputItemObj.m_revPtrVec).begin();
  while (vecIter != (inputItemObj.m_revPtrVec).end()) {
    (this->m_revPtrVec).push_back(new ItemRev(**vecIter));
  }
}

=========

// Derived classes
class JDI_ItemRev : public ItemRev {
  ...
}

class JDI_Item : public Item {

...

}

JDI_Item::JDI_Item(const JDI_Item &itemObj)
{
  // Copy contents of the input object's item rev pointer vector
  vector<ItemRev *>::const_iterator vecIter = (inputItemObj.m_revObjPtVec).begin();

  // The below does not work!
  while (vecIter != (inputItemObj.m_revObjPtVec).end()) {
    m_revObjPtVec.push_back(new JDI_ItemRev(**vecIter));
  }
}
```

The problem with the above is in the `push_back()` call in the `JDI_Item` copy constructor.

Given this setup, what should the child class's copy constructor look like? Do I even need a child class copy constructor? I assumed I did, because the copy constructor is creating new objects, and the parent copy constructor will create new objects that are not the type I want in the derived class (i.e., the parent object stores pointers to `ItemRev` objects, while the child object should store pointers to derived `JDI_ItemRev` objects).

Comment: You would need a copy-from-base constructor, something with the signature `JDI_Item::JDI_Item(const ItemRev &)`. This constructor isn't generated for you by default because it rarely makes sense.

Comment: First off, the `JDI_Item`-ctor is buggy. It leaks if any exception is thrown. Why do you have a `std::vector` of pointers to `JDI_ItemRev` anyway? Why aren't they directly in the vector, or at least managed by smart-pointers, anyway? (In the first case, the implicit definition should work.) Same can be said about `Item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is probably  a more succinct way to express this problem (i.e. your class structure needs some work).

However, if you want to do it this way, the easiest way to achieve it is to use a virtual clone() method in the base class of `ItemRev`, with overrides of it defined in derived classes.

e.g.:

```
class ItemRev {

  virtual ItemRev* clone() const = 0;
};

class JDI_ItemRev : public ItemRev {

  ItemRev* clone() const override 
  {
    // do your actual cloning here, using the copy constructor
    return new ItemRev(*this);
  }
};
```

Now, whenever you call `clone()` on any class derived from `ItemRev`, you will be returned an `ItemRev*` but it will point to a fully constructed derived class. You can of course get to the derived class's interface with `static_cast<>` or `dynamic_cast<>`.

...however...

derivation often seems like an easy win but it often turns out not to be. Inheritance should only be used if the derived class *really is a* type of the base class. Often people select inheritance when the derived class is *a lot like a* base class, or *shares many characteristics with* a base class. This is not the time to use inheritance. It's the time to use encapsulation.

In general, inheritance is evil.

On another note, you might find this link interesting.

[Presentation on inheritance as an implementation detail](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil)